# series involving a probability and Lambert W function

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ is a r.v. such that $E |X|^p < \infty$, $p \geq 1$ then $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log n} P[|X|^p > \frac{n}{\log n}] < \infty$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $(a_n)$ denote a bounded positive sequence such that the series $\sum\limits_na_n$ diverges. For every $n$, let $x_n=\sum\limits_{k\leqslant n}a_k$. Let $X\geqslant0$ denote a random variable. Then:
$$
E[X]\lt\infty\iff\sum\limits_na_nP[X\geqslant x_n]\lt\infty
$$